# Behavior of SMS Notifications

Tags: android, android-service, android-2.2-froyo

rite now i am trying to send SMS programmatically using following code , but i don't understand the behavior of SMS SENT Receiver.

> 1) for example if i send one SMS then `Activity.RESULT_OK`  inside 
>   `registerReceiver` is being called 3 times. and if i send 3 SMS using
>   for loopby calling `sendSMS` then  `Activity.RESULT_OK` is being
>   called 9 times. now i really don't know for one sms to send why this
>   registerReceiver is being called so many times?
>
> 2) Moreover , when i run this code over emulator i passed emulator
>   port to send SMS to other emulators which is natural but when i try to
>   send SMS to a real number then i am not getting SMS delivery failure
>   notification , as it notifies `Activity.RESULT_OK` only

**code to send SMS**

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
        {      

            String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
            String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

            PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(SENT), 0);

            PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
            Log.d("SMS Service", "SMS SEND CALLED");
            //---when the SMS has been sent---
            registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

                    Log.d("SMS Service", "RECEIVE CALLED");
                    switch (getResultCode())
                    {
                        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                            Toast.makeText(SMSService.this, "SMS sent", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            System.out.println("SMSService " + "SMS SENT");
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                            Toast.makeText(SMSService.this, "Generic failure", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            System.out.println("SMSService " + "GENERIC FAILURE");                          
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                            Toast.makeText(SMSService.this, "No service", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            System.out.println("SMSService " + "NO SERVICE");
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                            Toast.makeText(SMSService.this, "Null PDU", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            System.out.println("SMSService " + "Null PDU");
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                            Toast.makeText(SMSService.this, "Radio off", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            System.out.println("SMSService " + "Radio Off");
                            break;

                    }
                }
            }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

            //---when the SMS has been delivered---
            registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    switch (getResultCode())
                    {
                        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            System.out.println("SMSService " + "SMS Delivered");
                            break;
                        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            System.out.println("SMSService " + "SMS not delivered");                            
                            break;                      
                    }
                }
            }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);               
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general it depends on the size of message you are sending - if the message exceeds the single message limit (and in your case it sounds like it is about 3 times the single message limit) then you'll get a send and delivery report for each part of the message. Because you're not manually splitting the message you can't specify a different intent for each part.

It's worth taking a look at [SmsManager.divideMessage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#divideMessage%28java.lang.String%29) to split the message yourself and then at [SmsManager.sendMultiPartTextMessage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendMultipartTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.app.PendingIntent%3E,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.app.PendingIntent%3E%29) to do the actual sending. This allows you to specify different pending intents for different parts of the message and so you can determine when the message has been finally sent.

I think the emulator is treating all message destinations as accurate and since there's no network to come back and say otherwise you probably won't get a failure to send from the emulator (unless you did something like put the emulator in airplane mode). From experience you certainly do get those error codes on a real device.

**Edit:**
Thinking about it you're also registering the receiver each time you send the message, the code I use has a manifest registered receiver. There's a possibility that you've registered it multiple times (it lives as long as the context you're registering against) which would give it to you multiple times - this would also make it repeat probably 9 times for 3 messages (assuming the registration for the 3rd time made it before the send was completed for the first) - possible but I don't know how likely. You can test relatively well by logging the object in the registered receiver.

This is a cut down version of the code I use to send sms messages, it doesn't get repeated responses for messages:

```
ArrayList<String> split = SmsManager.getDefault().divideMessage(message);
ArrayList<PendingIntent> success = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>(partInfo.length);
Intent sendInt = null;
for (int i = 0; i < partInfo.length; i++)
{
   sendInt = new Intent(context.getPackageName() + RELAY_INTERNAL_RESPONSE);
   sendInt.putExtra(KEY_MESSAGEID, messageID);
   sendInt.putExtra(KEY_PART_NUMBER, i);
   sendInt.putExtra(KEY_REPLY_SEND_INTENT, sendIntAction);
   sendInt.putExtra(KEY_NUMBER, number);
   PendingIntent sendResult = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, i, sendInt, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT); //You have to use an incrementing request code to ensure you don't just get the same pending intent.
   success.add(sendResult);
}
ArrayList<PendingIntent> receipt = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>(partInfo.length);
sendInt = new Intent(context.getPackageName() + RELAY_INTERNAL_RECEIPT);
sendInt.putExtra(KEY_MESSAGEID, messageID);
sendInt.putExtra(KEY_REPLY_RECEIPT_INTENT, receiptIntAction);
sendInt.putExtra(KEY_NUMBER, number);
PendingIntent sendResult = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, nextReceiptCounter(context), sendInt, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
for (int i = 0; i < partInfo.length; i++)
{
   receipt.add(sendResult);
}
SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
sm.sendMultipartTextMessage(target, null, split, success, receipt);
```

And my receiver definition:

```
<receiver android:name="<package>.SMSBroadcastModule" 
      android:enabled="true" 
      android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="<package>.RELAY_INTERNAL_RESPONSE" />
                <action android:name="<package>.RELAY_INTERNAL_RESPONSE_RECEIPT" />
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: well my sms text is "John Right , This is my simple message !" , so this text isn't that much long right ? so still there is a need to use divideMessage ?

Comment: There is a need still (due to an HTC bug - which was annoying then it hit my app) but it shouldn't be causing a triple response on the pending intents.

Comment: Just updated with another possibility and some example code that at least works for me!

Comment: you were right as i was registering it again n again more over thanks for a quick n descriptive response n code sample it helps +1 for that too

Comment: @zeetoobiker Your example could prove to be a great help, just wondering what "partInfo" is and where you declare it? +1

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do a singleton Class for the register:

```
public class RegisterReceiverSingleton {
private static RegisterReceiverSingleton rrS;
public static final String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
public static final String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED"; 
private RegisterReceiverSingleton(final Context ctx){
    //when the SMS has been sent
            ctx.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                        switch (getResultCode())
                        {
                            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                                Toast.makeText(ctx, "SMS Enviado", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Generic failure", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                                Toast.makeText(ctx, "No service", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Null PDU", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Radio off", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

            //when the SMS has been delivered
            ctx.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    switch (getResultCode())
                    {
                        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, "SMS Entregado", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, "SMS No Entregado", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;                        
                    }
                }
            }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
}

public static RegisterReceiverSingleton getInstance(final Context ctx){
    if(rrS==null){
        rrS = new RegisterReceiverSingleton(ctx);
    }
    return rrS;
}
```

}